# How to handle different classes of users in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-datastore

I plan to use Google Accounts to authenticate users of my GAE app.
As i understand it, all owners of a gmail adress are considered equal and can be authentified.
My app providing a free trial mode that requires no login, i'm only interested to authentify my paying customers.

Maybe I miss something, but the only distinction between users mentioned in the docs is between [admins/non admins](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers).

What is the common practice to authenticate a specific class of users (in my case: paying users) in GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at gae-biolerplate, it shows how to create a user class using different logins

If you want to have extra information on users use a new model ie UserExtra to add information 
like ie paid etc

[link to boilerplate](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate)